# Hide/remove buttons from keyboard

Tags: ios, button, keyboard, hide

Is it possible to access/remove buttons from the keyboard on **iPad**?

I want the user to have access only to the number keyboard without possibility to switch between other types of keyboard. For this, i need to hide/disable "switch buttons" (buttons with label "ABC").

[image: keyboard]

To access the keyboard i use:

```
UIWindow * tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
UIView* keyboard;

for(int i = 0; i < [tempWindow.subviews count]; i++)
{
    keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES)
    {
          // access elements of keyboard
    }
 }
```

Also, the problem is that `[keyboard.subviews count] = 0` , while the keyboard was found.

Answer (score 1):

Each `UITextField` conforms to text input protocol called `UITextInputTraits` which declares property `keyboardType`. You can define the keyboard in interface builder or calling `setKeyboardType:` method on your text field. The keyboard types are defined in documentation. In your particular case you should use `UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad` for number input.